# Azure B2C Custom Policy Transformation and Single Backslash

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Trying to add a single backslash \ in a ClaimTransformation but it always tries to escape it \. When I add '\\' I get '\\\\', etc...

```
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="PrependAD" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_signinName"
            TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string"
            Value="AD\{0}" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_signinName"
            TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

The claim ends up as "extension_signinName":"AD\\" instead of "AD\"

Any ideas.

thank you